# STB Image Implementation with tinygltf and sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

I am including both tinygltf and sfml in my project. When I include tinygltf with these options:

```
#define TINYGLTF_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <tiny_gltf.h>
```

I get multiple definition errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: sfml/lib/libsfml-graphics-s.a(ImageLoader.cpp.o): multiple definition of 'stbi_write_jpg'
/usr/bin/ld.gold: _objs/client_lib/loader.pic.o: previous definition here
```

That is just a small snippet of the errors, but for most stb functions, there is a similar error. So I tried to fix this by including tinygltf like this:

```
#define TINYGLTF_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <tiny_gltf.h>
```

However, now there is just one singular error:

```
_objs/client_lib/loader.pic.o:loader.cpp:function tinygltf::LoadImageData(tinygltf::Image*, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, int, int, unsigned char const*, int, void*): error: undefined reference to 'stbi_is_16_bit_from_memory'
```

It seems like the two libraries are depending on slightly different versions of stb. Is there any way to fix this?

I'm using tinygltf version 2.2.0, and sfml version 2.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're linking SFML statically, you're integrating all the symbols of SFML in your application including the STB symbols.

I see two different solutions here, maybe there are more:

- Update the STB header in the SFML extlibs/ directory and rebuild SFML
- Link SFML dynamically, so your application doesn't see the SFML STB symbols

Comment: I just found that I can have a binary with relative paths for dynamic libraries. Thank you for you help.